# How do I use CDK to create an RDS with master credentials managed by AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

How do I create RDS with reference to Secrets Manager with CDK such as [image]

My script as below creates a string but not a dynamic reference to the Secrets:

```
    const masterSecret = new cdk.aws_secretsmanager.Secret(
      this, `${id}-masterSecret`,{        
        secretName: `${id}-masterSecret`,
        encryptionKey: rdsCredentialKey,        
      }
    );

    // Create a secret in Secrets Manager to store the RDS credentials
    const credentialSecret = new cdk.aws_rds.DatabaseSecret(this, 
      `${id}-credential`, 
    {
      username: "credentialSecret",      
      secretName: `${id}-credential`,
      encryptionKey: rdsCredentialKey,
    });

    const instanceProps = <cdk.aws_rds.DatabaseInstanceProps>{
      engine: cdk.aws_rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.postgres({
        version: cdk.aws_rds.PostgresEngineVersion.VER_15_3
      }),
      vpc,
      subnetGroup:subnetGroup,
      publiclyAccessible: publiclyAccessible,      
      credentials: cdk.aws_rds.Credentials.fromSecret(credentialSecret),

      instanceIdentifier: `${id}-rds`,

      instanceType: cdk.aws_ec2.InstanceType.of(cdk.aws_ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE4_GRAVITON, cdk.aws_ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),

      storageType: cdk.aws_rds.StorageType.GP3,      
    };
```

Comment: This should be generating a managed secret within Secret Manager for you - you don't need to provide an encryption key. Can you detail further what's missing in your current setup?